# C: Why fabs giving weird result while comparing floating point numbers?

Tags: c, floating-point

I have a small simple code to compare 2 floating point numbers:

I tried using fabs but it gives wrong weird result. What is the mistake, and what is the correct form?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <float.h>

void compareFloat(double a1, double a2)
{
   if(fabs(a1 - a2) < DBL_EPSILON)
       printf("a1 is smaller\n");
   else
       printf("a1 is larger\n");
}

int main()
{
 float a1=0.0000004f, a2=0.0005f;
 compareFloat(a1, a2);
}
```

What is the mistake in this code? It always prints `a1 is smaller` even if i set a1=0.004f and a2=0.0005f

Comment: What are you expecting it to say?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is mathematically wrong. You're actually trying to compare if both floats are equal, not larger/smaller.

To compare which one is larger, just use the `operator<`, for example like this:

```
if( abs(a1 - a2) > DBL_EPSILON && a1 < a2 )
// ....
```

---

Suppose: `a1 == 1.` and `a2 == 5.`. Then `fabs( a1 - a2 )` will be larger than `DBL_EPSILON`, BUT this does **not** mean, that `a1 > a2`.

---

And the other error is already mentioned - `abs` is for `int`egers, you need `fabs`.

---

---

**EDIT**: I'd create an additional function for comparing floating point numbers, for example:

```
bool areEqual( double x, double y )
{
     return ( fabs( x - y ) < DBL_EPSILON );
}
```

and then use it directly - will make your code more readable. Example usage:

```
if( areEqual( a1, a2 ) )
    // equal
else if( a1 < a2 )  // here, it's guaranteed, that a1 != a2, so it's safe now
    // a1 is smaller
else
    // a2 is smaller
```

Comment: Since a1 and a2 are both floats, does directly using `a1 < a2` is fine?

Comment: @kingsmasher1 - well, depends. Suppose `a1 == 10 ^ (-10)` and `a2 == 10 ^ (-11)` - are they equal or `a1 > a2`? Depends on the necessary precision.

Comment: Sorry, my doubt still remains the same. It gives correct answer, but can we compare floating point numbers using logical operators in C? I guess no, so what is the corresponding workaround? `float a1 =0.002` and `float a2 = 0.00002` i think a1 < a2 is not valid.

Comment: @kingsmasher1 - what do you mean by "logical operators"?

Comment: i mean `<, >, ==, !=` etc can't be used for comparing floating point numers, or am i wrong for some exceptions?

Comment: These are not logical operators (logical are `||, &&, ^, etc`). But it's fine, they _can_ be used. The problem is only, when the numbers are very, very close to each other. See my edit.

Comment: In `areEqual()`, suspect you want `fabs()` and not `fans()`.

Comment: Further,  I do not this `fabs( x - y ) < DBL_EPSILON` is what is desired.  The `DBL_EPSILON` should be replaced by some `DBL_EPSILON*fabs(x)` or some other scaling on `DBL_EPSILON`.

Comment: The relational and equality operators work without errors. They are not part of any problem with comparing floating-point numbers. The actual problem is that floating-point numbers often have errors from **earlier** operations. That means the numbers you have are **wrong**. **Any** operation you perform on them gives a wrong result. E.g., `sqrt(x)` and `acos(x)` fail if the errors in `x` make it negative or greater than one, respectively. `x+y` is wrong if `x` or `y` is wrong. Allowing generic tolerances in comparisons, rather than ones tailored to a particular program, is not the right fix.

Comment: @KirilKirov: You can check the code now, just now publicized it in ideone: http://ideone.com/3OjAUC

Comment: @kingsmasher1  Your run time error may be fixed by `float a1, a2` --> `double float a1, a2;`

Comment: @chux: what about the logical error in comparing equal numbers?

Comment: There is not a logical C error comparing equal numbers.  I suspect the concern @Kiril Kirov and many have is that since C floating point math is not infinitively precise, programmers can have a logical error in their thinking when using a==b.  Contrived example:`for (float x=0; 1; x += 0.01;) { if (x == 2) break; }` may loop seemingly forever as when `x` get near 2, it may not _exactly_ equal 2 and so always fail the `if()`.  Better to do `if (x >= 1.995)`. This is getting off a bit topic, so maybe check for existing answers or post a question.

Comment: @chux: 1. Yes, I meant `fabs`. 2. I didn't get your point about the scaling. 3. Yes, that's exactly what I meant - about your last comment and the precision of the floating point numbers. Nice example!

Comment: @kingsmasher1 - the links you provided, give me correct results - I tried with `1.2`. BUT, they may show you different results, because you actually have undefined behavior in that code - you read `double`s (using `scanf`'s `%lf`), while your variables are `float`s (_not_ doubles). This _undefined behavior_ may cause a lot of troubles (literally - anything can happen).

Comment: @EricPostpischil - thanks for the clarification, I should have mentioned this in my answer. Really helpful comment.

Comment: Point about the scaling: Why I suggest `...<(DBL_EPSILON*fabs(x))` vs.  `...<DBL_EPSILON`.  Think of comparing x=1e-100 to y=2e-100. `areEqual()` returns true because |x-y| < DBL_EPSILON, which is ~ 2e-16 depending on platform. Since y is twice x, I'd expect false.  Think of comparing x=1e+100 to y=1.0000000000000002e+100. `areEqual()` returns false. Since y is the next float-point number after x, I'd expect true.  Scaling DBL_EPSILON by x (or the larger of |x|,|y|) solves this issue.  The code realization is shown in my post.

Comment: @KirilKirov: Thanks, yeah i was using 0.001 for both a and b, and using scanf %lf shows wrong result. I got your point. Thank you. Thanks to "chux" too.

Comment: @chux - I see, it's interesting solution. I'd say, that it depends on the situation. The solution, you suggest, sounds great, but it may be unnecessary and it may (essentially) slow down the execution of some code, depending on how critical it is and how often it is executed. Again - that's really clever, I'll up-vote your answer, but it _does_ depend on the situation.

Answer (score 4):

The prototype for abs is an integer!

```
int abs (int number);
```

You want fabs for floating point

```
double fabs (double number);
```

Comment: I maintain that everyone falls for this exactly once in their programming lives.

Comment: Using fabs gives wrong result too, it prints `a1 is larger` which is wrong again !!

Comment: Are you sure you're using fabs properly? All it does is strip '-' from negative numbers.

Comment: And then of course for extra fun abs can work with floats in c++ depending on whether you include cmath or not.

Comment: @kingsmasher1: comparing the absolute value of the difference of two values tells you nothing about which one is larger.

Answer (score 3):

`fabs(a1 - a2) < DBL_EPSILON` takes the "floating" out of floating point numbers (FP).

FP numbers are logarithmically distributed. `fabs(a1 - a2) < DBL_EPSILON` will always be false for large different numbers, even if `a1,a2` are adjacent FP values.  `fabs(a1 - a2) < DBL_EPSILON` is always true for small FP numbers, even when they differ by many magnitudes of value.

Instead, scale the *epsilon*.

Compare the 2 numbers into 5 results

```
void compareFloat(double a1, double a2) {
  if(a1 == a2) // Typically not performed is applications, but here for illustration.
   printf("a1 is exactly equal to a2\n");
  else if(fabs(a1 - a2) <= (DBL_EPSILON *fabs(a1)) )
   printf("a1 is nearly equal to a2\n");
  else if(a1 < a2)
   printf("a1 is smaller than a2\n");
  else if(a1 > a2)
    printf("a1 is larger than a2\n");
  else 
    printf("a1 is not comparable to a2, at least one of them is a Not-a-Number\n");
}
```

As others have said, be sure to use `fabs()` instead of `abs()`.

Comment: I wouldn't do this: `a1 == a2`.

Comment: 2 `double`s can be compare for exact equality.  I suspect @Kiril Kirov justifiable concern is likely with typical applications where comparing 2 `double`s for exact equality is frown upon.  I rarely do it.  After 2 doubles are calculated via various means, there are not exactly what you expect, but only nearly what one expects.

Comment: "After 2 doubles are calculated via various means, there are not exactly what you expect, but only nearly what one expects" - exactly my point. I mean - you _can_ use `operator==`, but I don't think one can rely on this.

Comment: @KirilKirov The function in the second half of this blog post relies on `==` between `double` numbers in three places; in two instances the number being compared is computed from an arbitrary user input. Still, the function work when compiled in a strict IEEE 754 programming environment (GCC flags `-msse2 -mfpmath=sse`). According to you, it should not work, then? http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2013/05/01/A-conversionless-conversion-function2

Comment: @PascalCuoq - I never said anything about being wrong or will / won't work.